# Passing object from Main() to function changes the object , even though C# is by value?

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

Consider the following code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test
{
    class Person
    {
        public Person(String name)
        {
            this.first = name;
        }


        private String first;
        public void setName(String name)
        {
            this.first = name;
        }

        public String getName()
        {
            return this.first;
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        public static void changeName(Person per)
        {
            per.setName("Jack");
        }

        public static void changeToNull(Person per)
        {
            per = null;          
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Person p = new Person("David");
            Console.WriteLine(p.getName());
            changeName(p);
            Console.WriteLine(p.getName());
            changeToNull(p);
            Console.WriteLine(p.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

The output is :

```
David
Jack
Jack
```

From my understanding C# is by value , so why when passing `p` to `changeName()` , it also changes the `p` in Main() , but when I set it to `null` , it keeps `Jack` !?

Comment: The *reference* is passed by value. The value of `p` itself is unchanged - it's still a reference to the same object as before. However, the state of the object itself has changed. See http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: The argument is by value, yes, but the argument is itself a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Person is a reference type, so when you pass it to changeName as value what you are really passing is a pointer (address) to that Person object in memory.  Since that pointer is passed by value you can't re-assign it to a different copy of Person, but you can call methods on that object that may change its internal state.  The method changeToNull behaves the way it does because the pointer to Person per is again passed by value.  When you set per to null you are only changing the pointer local to the changeToNull method.